# setting the current date using setState in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui datepicker and I want the current date in the state to be changed as user switches from one date to another.

Here is the link to the materialUi datepicker I am using.[link](https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/#date-pickers)

I used this method but it doesn't work and does mot show anything in event related to the date we moved to .
This is the return part where I did onChange .

```
return(
            <form className={classes.container} noValidate>
          <TextField
            id="date"
            type="date"
            defaultValue={today}
            onChange={this.handleDate}
            className={classes.textField}
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />
          </form>
      );
```

Here is the part where I changed the state

```
handleDate=(event,date)=>{
        console.log('incoming1',event);
      //   console.log('incoming',date);
       this.setState({
         todaydate: date
     });
 }
```

Comment: According to the docs there's no second argument in the handler function; the new value can be accessed using `event.target.value`.

Comment: what is `today` in `defaultValue={today}`?

Comment: try this https://reactdatepicker.com/ very simple to use

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want, you can access the value in the object event.

```
handleDate=(event)=>{
       this.setState({
         todaydate: event.target.value
     });
 }
```

Comment: event.target.value contains the actual value of the calendar date that is been selected , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `onBlur` event on date picker.

```
    <TextField
        id="date"
        type="date"
        defaultValue={today}
        onBlur={handleDate}
        onChange={this.handleDate}
        className={classes.textField}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
      />
```

then handleChange should be like this.

```
handleDate=(event)=>{
   this.setState({
     todaydate: event.target.value
 });
}
```